# Create a binary output raster using an algorithm of reflectance indices

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, multi-band, binary

I'm attempting to create a binary output raster in ArcMap based on an algorithm that uses three different reflectance index rasters I've already created from Landsat 5 data (mNDWI, NDVI, and EVI)the identify surface water pixels. The algorithm I need to apply is:

(mNDWI-NDVI>0 OR mNDWI-EVI>0) AND (EVI<0.1)

I need every pixel that the expression is true for to = 1, and every other pixel to = 0.

I tried stacking the three index rasters using the Composite Bands tool and then using the Band Arithmetic raster function, but the algorithm was invalid.

Is there a way to accomplish this in ArcMap?

Comment: Do you have a spatial analyst license? To do this I would use Con, the equation looks ok but change to (mNDWI-NDVI>0 | mNDWI-EVI>0) &(EVI<0.1) read more here https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000z7000000 (Con can be run directly from the toolbox or within Raster Calculator if you're more comfortable that way).

Comment: @MichaelStimson This approach seemed to have worked. It did return a binary raster but some of the pixels were falsely identified as water, so I may have to edit the expression a bit. Thank you for your help though!